# Linkedin API: Editing licenses and certifications

Tags: linkedin-api

My company has recently started offering certifications, and I'm looking to add them to a users profile using the linkedin api.

I can see from the documentation that I need access to the `w_compliance` permission in order to edit someone's profile, but I can't see any way to get this permission through self-serve, and none of the four linkedin partner programs seem relevant.

Does anyone know if it's still possible to get this permission?